# Request to generate report with id using python

Tags: python, api

Using this python code to generate report id from a data online platform using their api.

**Here is the code :**

```
import requests 

import json

api_url = 'https://www.lytics.com/api/insights/v1/reports'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'.
    'X-access-key': 'e13168e9f4550'
}

r = requests.post(url=api_url, headers=headers)

print(r.content)
```

Getting this **error message :**

> {"code":400,"message":"Invalid input parameters","status":"error"}'

Comment: You have an error in your headers you use '.' instead of ','. Also make sure that your access key works

Comment: mistake while posting the code. not working even with , and key is working.

Comment: I tried this url https://api.lytics.io/api/segment?access_token=e13168e9f4550 but returns not authorized